# Making a 2 tables join in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, phpmyadmin

Been trying to make a join between 2 of my tables, tried all kind of inputs but all seem wrong, could anyone help me?

Both tables got "ID" in common.

```
SELECT dmb.Antal ben
     , dmb.ID
     , dmb.Navn
     , sadb.ID
     , sadb.Pris
  FROM dmb
 INNER
  JOIN sadb
    ON sadb.ID = dmb.ID
 WHERE dyr med ben.ID ID=1
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are incorporating spaces in your table and column names. This is a seriously bad idea. Also, you seem to be uncertain what the name of your tables are. With lots of assumptions, a valid query may look like this:

```
SELECT dmb.`Antal ben`
     , dmb.ID
     , dmb.Navn
     , sadb.ID
     , sadb.Pris
  FROM `dyr med ben` dmb
 INNER
  JOIN sadb
    ON sadb.ID = dmb.ID
 WHERE dmb.ID = 1
```

Also, aren't vertebrates 'virveldyr' ??

Comment: i changed the name of Antal ben to Antalben which seems to help. 
I get the error: #1054 - Unknown column 'dmd.ID' in 'Where clause' now

Answer (score -1):

```
      $answer = "SELECT dmb.Antal ben, dmb.ID, dmb.Navn, sadb.ID, sadb.Pris
                 FROM dyr med bens.dmb
                 INNER JOIN  dyr med bens.sadb
                 ON dmb.ID = sadb.ID
                 WHERE ben.ID = 1"
```

try this